# wordpress - changing where meta tags are shown in the head section

Tags: wordpress

Please can someone tell me how I can change the position of my meta tags within my Wordpress theme so that they appear immediately after the initial "head" tag.

The reason is that when I look at the source code of my webpage I can see all my css code before I see my meta descriptions

BUT, the problem is, BING does not fetch the entire page, but only the first so many 1000s characters and as such it is not finding my "title" or "meta" tags and so my SERP listings are basically blank

If I can move the generation of my meta data "higher up" in the head tag and before the CSS then this will solve the problem beautifully.

The issue is, I have no idea how to do this...I think it something to do with the wp_head() function but whatever changes I've made have made no difference

I am using the all-in-one seo plugin if that makes any difference

Thanks in advance as this has been driving me nuts for weeks and I will confess that I'm not very good with wordpress as I am of a "certain age" where I still think DOS is wonderful :-) :-)

Dan

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your theme (and maybe plugins). You should check in your theme's `header.php` if you can find it. Most of what is in the `<head>` is done by the [wp_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/). Both theme's and plugin can add stuff inside that with the [hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

I can't help any more without you providing more info (and code).
Hope this will get you started.

**Rough steps;**
Find where the `<meta>` tags are added, look for the `wp_head` reference.
Once you find it, use [remove_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/). Then re-add it with a higher priority with [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).Look for the priority argument.
This way you can do it in your own theme, or a small custom plugin. You don't want to touch the plugin files or wp-core.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

I've searched the entire source code and found plenty of add_action('wp_head'...) commands in different files but is there a way of knowing / specifying the order in which WP will execute them?

Sorry if I'm being dim :-)

Comment: See my updated answer for more info, but [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) has a priority argument. But most will probably be added at the default prio of 10. In that case it's just a matter of which file runs first, you can't see it directly.